# How can I change the speed of slider using arrow in Slick Carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, carousel, slick.js

I have created a logo slider which displays similar to marquee. **What I want to do is to add next/prev arrows that can accelerate the speed of slider when click next arrow and reverse the slider when click prev arrow.** I currently use slick carousel to make it.

Also I have no idea why sometimes my carousel pause for a second then continue, can anyone help me with this?

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.marquee-logo').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    infinite: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 0,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    arrows: false,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    speed: 6500,
    initialSlide: 1,
    draggable: false,
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="marquee-logo">
  <div class="slider-logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slider-logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slider-logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slider-logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="slider-logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/takumi24/pen/JRzEjA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be used to make slider slow

```
 $("#slowbutton").click(function(){

 $('.marquee-logo').slick('unslick');

 $('.marquee-logo').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  infinite: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 0,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  arrows: false,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  speed: 10000,
  initialSlide: 1,
  draggable: false,
  });});
```

This for making faster

```
  $("#nextbutton").click(function(){
  $('.marquee-logo').slick('unslick');

 $('.marquee-logo').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  infinite: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 0,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  arrows: false,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  speed: 300,
  initialSlide: 1,
  draggable: false,
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yawgra

On button click first destroy the slider and add slider again with increased/decreased speed

You can also try by this   `$('.marquee-logo').slick('slickSetOption', 'speed', 500,true);` with out destroying the slider

But speed change by slickSetOption method  cause a delay:issue https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2334

Comment: I didn't try this yet, will update the result once I did this soon

Answer (score 0):

User [XZY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7011496/xyz)'s answer worked for me. While playing with it I also noticed that `slick` (at least in the implementation I was using) exposes an `options` property which is modifiable. So the below might work as well:

```
var slickSlider = $('.marquee-logo')[0]

slickSlider.slick.options.autoplaySpeed = 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the SPEED property, that should be it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-slider').slick({
    speed: 3000
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).